# Configuring App Sandbox before Build

Tags: ios, core-audio, sandbox, audioqueue

I think my question is how do I pre-configure my iOS sandbox to have an audio file in it so after I build I can immediately test my Audio Queue structure.

I am working on an iOS app to play audio from a stream I am hosting on my server. Before I tackle how to get data from a HTTP stream, I thought I would start off by using Audio Queue Services to play a file from my phone. It is my understanding that if you want to play multiple audio streams at once you have to use Audio Queue as opposed to AVPlayer or any of the other services.

The problem I have is I can't configure my CFURLRef because I can't find my file.

```
AudioBufferPlayer *player = (AudioBufferPlayer*) inUserData;

if (player.playing) {

    NSString *path = @"/Users/acopp/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/F9CA1197-A661-4B2F-9B42-68A991F61B19/";
    const char *filePath = [path cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    CFURLRef audioFileURL = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(NULL, (const UInt8*)filePath, strlen(filePath), false);

    OSStatus result = AudioFileOpenURL(audioFileURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, kAudioFileCAFType, player.mAudioFile); 

    UInt32 numBytesReadFromFile;
    UInt32 numPackets = player.mNumPacketsToRead;

    AudioFileReadPackets(
                         *(player.mAudioFile),
                         false,
                         &numBytesReadFromFile,
                         NULL,
                         player.mCurrentPacket,
                         &numPackets,
                         inBuffer->mAudioData
                         );

    if (numPackets > 0) {
        inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize = numBytesReadFromFile;
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAudioQueue, inBuffer, 0, NULL);
        player.mCurrentPacket += numPackets;
    }
```

I get an error saying EXC_BAD_ACCESS at my AudioFileReadPackets and my OSStatus result is set to -50 at this point so I think my AudioFileOpenURL call is failing.

I think my problem is my *path isn't really pointing to anything at this point. The problem is when I go to

```
@"/Users/acopp/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/F9CA1197-A661-4B2F-9B42-68A991F61B19/"
```

My four options are Demo3, Documents, Library, and temp. None of these have my quick.caf file that I added to my project.

**TL,DR - Unless I overlooked something, I believe I am asking how to add audio files to my sandbox before I build so I can test my code on the iPhone Simulator.**

Answer (score 0):

Files you add to your project end up in your app's Bundle directory, not Documents or Library/Caches.  For the Simulator, this app bundle is usually inside an Xcode Build or DerivedData directory, not the Simulator Application Support area.

One easy method to get a good path is to, during the first run of the app, create some tiny dummy file in the app's sandbox Documents or Library/Caches directory with some unique name.  Quit the app, remove this file creation code, and then use Spotlight on the Mac to find the dummy file.  Replace with whatever you want.  Then run the app, with code reading from the same path use to create the dummy file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

to get to your files that are included in your project.